# Uppercase Greek in Roman - TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht, greek

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:ocdphi}
E(\Delta\phi_{r,j}^s)&=g^s_r\tilde{\tau}_r+d\tilde{t}_r-d\tilde{t}^s-\mu_j\tilde{\iota}_r^s+\tilde{\delta}_{r,j}-\tilde{\delta}_{,j}^s+\lambda_j\tilde{z}_{r,j}^s,\\\label{eq:ocdp}
E(\Delta p_{r,j}^s)&=g^s_r\tilde{\tau}_r+d\tilde{t}_r-d\tilde{t}^s+\mu_j\tilde{\iota}_r^s+\tilde{d}_{r,j}-\tilde{d}^s_{,j},
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

DVI output `\Delta` symbol came in roman font, but in HTML output, it came in italic font. how can I fix it?

I am running the command:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,mathml,mathml-" " -cunihft" " -cvalidate -p"
```

Please suggest...

Comment: Please do not introduce tags that are not reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical characters are output in the `<mi>` character by `tex4ht`, which is rendered as italics by browser by default. The following configuration will require the normal font:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\let\oldDelta\Delta
\def\Delta{\HCode{<mi mathvariant="normal">}\PauseMathClass\oldDelta\EndPauseMathClass\HCode{</mi>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\PauseMathClass` command will prevent insertion of the second `<mi>` element, which would happen otherwise.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, so need to redefine all Uppercase Greek else any global options available?

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes, they need to be redefined as well. I may add it to `tex4ht` sources.